# Can I differentiate this summation like this?

Tags: derivatives

Faulhaber's formula is $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p=\frac1{1+p}\sum_{j=0}^p(-1)^j\binom{p+1}{j}B_jn^{p+1-j}$

I was wondering if I could differentiate this with respect to $p$.

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(k)k^p=\frac1{1+p}\left(\frac{d}{dp}\sum_{j=0}^p(-1)^j\binom{p+1}{j}B_jn^{p+1-j}\right)-\frac1{(1+p)^2}\sum_{j=0}^p(-1)^j\binom{p+1}{j}B_jn^{p+1-j}$

And I was wondering how to differentiate that first summation, mainly, the part with the binomial coefficient/combination thing.

Comment: Since the $p$ appears as the upper limit of a sum, it is a discrete variable and you can't differentiate with respect to it here. (Everything else could be handled, including the binomial coefficient.)

Comment: @GregMartin Could you rewrite the sum as some sort of integral?  Then differentiate?

Comment: The problem with that is, the formula is proved for integer values of $p$. To differentiate it, you have to convert both sides to depend on continuous $p$. Even if you find a way to do this, you have to be sure that the extensions you've chosen on both sides are the same. That is, you need to prove that the fomula still holds with your extensions. If you can extend them in a differentiable fashion, and prove the formula still holds, then yes you can differentiate them.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Oh... ok.  Sorry if I don't quite know how to do things like that, I haven't 'technically' taken any Calculus.  ;)

Comment: And as GregMartin has pointed out, neither do other people. You can't just make things happen by wishing. How to extend the LHS to non-integer $p$ is obvious. How to extend the RHS to non-integer $p$ is not - particularly when it *still has to agree with the LHS for all $p$*.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yeah, thanks.  Your input and his are much appreciated.

Comment: @PaulSinclair not that I wish to continue with this... but https://cyclochaotic.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/the-derivative-of-summation-rule/

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense (he specifies that $a(x), b(x)$ are integer when $x$ is an integer, but the summation is only defined when $a(x), b(x)$ are integer, and what he does requires $x$ to not be integer, and $a,b$ to be continuous.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Have you tried it with the above problem and found numerical inconsistencies?  If there aren't much, I'd rather just accept the formula as something that works for the general case.  Also, summations aren't always defined only when the upper and lower bounds/limits are integers, they are also defined when the difference between the upper and lower bounds are integers as well.  I think he is merely asking that it be possible to define the sum when $a,b$ are continuous, then the derivative can be given.  So take it on faith that $\sum_{n=1}^{3/2}n=\frac{15}8$.

Comment: None of that applies to the problem I mentioned. And I hardly can look for numerical inconsistencies when there are glaring logical inconsistencies to be handled first. Besides which, differentiation is not really a numerical process. You can approximate it numerically, but that approximation is unstable and has to be treated with great care. He may have a solution for the problem. But I could not see it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair When I said to check it numerically, I meant to compare the LHS to the RHS using the given formula.  I can't do it because I don't think I have a calculator capable and because I don't understand how to use the formula.  Anyways, thanks for pointing things out, I don't mean to waste your time with this problem anyways, its not important.